# need a tool or editor to read SAS files for free

Tags: sas

Need a free editor or tool to read/open .sas7bat or .wpd files.Trying to open/read a sas files.I don`t have SAS installed

tried using sublime and notepad++

Comment: You can easile convert dataset from R, python, or whatever

Answer (score 4):

SAS provides a tool called [SAS® Universal Viewer](http://support.sas.com/software/products/univiewer/index.html)

From the link:

> **The SAS Universal Viewer** is a replacement for the SAS System Viewer. The SAS Universal Viewer enables you to view, sort, and filter SAS data sets and other simple text-based files. You cannot edit SAS data sets with the SAS Universal Viewer. You do not have to invoke SAS or install SAS on your computer in order to use the SAS Universal Viewer.
>
> **The most recent release is SAS Universal Viewer 1.42.**

Comment: you can use WPS Workbench

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free tool: [www.clinbay.com/datasly](https://www.clinbay.com/datasly) which allows to open SAS datasets in .sas7bdat and XPT formats, and also export them to Excel format as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull them into R using the Haven package (part of the tidyverse)
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/readme/README.html